# Servlet 3: Async - cant PUSH partial response

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, push, servlet-3.0

I am using Tomcat 7. When my asynchronous servlet tries to *PUSH* partial response to client at different intervals, it does not work.. The response gets flushed only after the whole response is ready.

How to PUSH partial response?

Here is my code

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/home"} , name="asynch", asyncSupported=true)
public class CometServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        final  AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();
        new MyThread(ac).start();
    }
}
```

What **MyThread** does is it will write numbers from 1 to 10 to the reponse object at regular intervals.

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    AsyncContext ac;
    public MyThread( AsyncContext ac ) {
        this.ac = ac;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int i =2 ; 
        while( i < 10 )
        {
            try
            {
            ac.getResponse().getWriter().print(i + "\n" );
            ac.getResponse().getWriter().flush();
            ac.getResponse().flushBuffer();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ccttt " + e);
            }
            i++;
        }
        ac.complete();
    }
}
```

And the page that requests the servlet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show()
{
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Comet/home", true );
xml.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xml.readyState== 3|| xml.readyState == 4 ) {
    document.getElementById("dynamicContent").innerHTML=xml.responseText;
    }
}
xml.send(null);
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="show" onclick="show()"/> 
<div id="dynamicContent"> </div>
```

After about 10 seconds I see the complete response on the browser. But I want to see the partial outputs every second.

All i want to learn is how to PUSH partial response with Servlet 3 API.

Can someone answer this question?

Comment: @NobVenoda Nope!!.  Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788371/java-servlet-3-0-server-push-sending-data-multiple-times-using-same-asynccontex/16928314#16928314) for this exact same problem mentioned in another question.
If you still face this problem after following the instructions in that answer, do let me know.