# Java Servlet 3.0 server push: Sending data multiple times using same AsyncContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-3.0, server-push

Lead by several examples and questions answered here ( mainly 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html?page=3 ), I want to have server sending the response multiple times to a client without completing the request. When request times out, I create another one and so on.

I want to avoid long polling, since I have to recreate request every time I get the response. (and that quite isn't what async capabilities of servlet 3.0 are aiming at).

I have this on server side:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/home"}, name = "async", asyncSupported = true) 

public class CometServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync(request, response);

        HashMap<String, AsyncContext> store = AppContext.getInstance().getStore();

        store.put(request.getParameter("id"), ac);

    }
}
```

And a thread to write to async context.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    String id, message;

    public MyThread(String id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void run() {
        HashMap<String, AsyncContext> store = AppContext.getInstance().getStore();
        AsyncContext ac = store.get(id);
        try {
            ac.getResponse().getWriter().print(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I make the request, data is sent only if I call `ac.complete()`. Without it request will always timeout. So basically I want to have data "streamed" before request is completed.

Just to make a note, I have tried this with `Jetty 8` Continuation `API`, I also tried with printing to `OutputStream` instead of `PrintWriter`. I also tried `flushBuffer()` on response. Same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Client side is done like this:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/home', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 3 || xhr.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("dynamicContent").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
```

Can someone at least confirm that server side is okay? :)

Comment: can you post your xml configs ?

Comment: There is no XML config for this servlet, its 3.0 spec and configured with Annotations (see above, asyncSupported = true) However, if I furn that to false, servlet fails on `startAsync()` line. So its configured fine.

Also, when I run `curl` from cmd to that address, it is displaying data in chunks as expected.

So my conclusion is that JS code on client side is wrong.

Comment: Did this work for you at all ?

Comment: No, it didn't. Sorry I didn't reply sooner. I've tried that with both jQuery .ajax call and XMLHttpRequest. Request is pending and never triggers `readystatechange`.

Comment: Nob, Can you pls tell if my new answer works for you ? Or did you figure out any other way to solve it ? In any case, am interested to know. Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

Your server-side and client-side code is indeed ok.
The problem is actually with your browser buffering **text/plain** responses from your web-server. 
This is the reason you dont see this issue when you use curl.

I took your client-side code and I was able to see incremental responses, with **only** just one little change:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

The incremental responses showed up immediately regardless of their size.

Without that setting, when my output was a small message, it was considered as text/plain and wasnt showing up at the client immediately. When I kept adding more and more to the client responses, it got accumulated until the buffer size reached **about 1024 bytes** and then the whole thing showed up on the client side. After that point, however, the small increments showed up immediately (no more accumulation).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, didn't see this until now. I will try it out! I am really swamped with other issues atm. :) Will let you know as soon as I try it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but you can just flushBuffer on the response as well.