# Want to start a thread on server for each client

Tags: java, sockets, timer, client-server

Basically I want whenever Client connect It would send a String "connect" to Server. In response Server should start a thread for that client which will keep sending "Awake" message to client after 5 seconds.

I have used Timer class with Server but it is unable to ping client on same socket. Can you tell me some way for this. Sample code will be beneficial.

code: -

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Server2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server ob = new Server();
        ob.dt();
    }
}

class Server {

    public static Socket socket;

    public void dt() {
        try {

            int port = 25000;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");

            // Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop
            while (true) {
                // Reading the message from the client
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String number = br.readLine();
                if (number.equals("2")) {
                    System.out.println("asda");
                    TimerExampleRepeating tr = new TimerExampleRepeating();
                    tr.heartbeat(this);
                } else if (number.equals("disconnect")) {
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Message received from client is " + number);

                    // Multiplying the number by 2 and forming the return message
                    String returnMessage;
                    try {
                        int numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        int returnValue = numberInIntFormat * 2;
                        returnMessage = String.valueOf(returnValue) + "\n";
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        // Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
                        returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
                    }

                    // Sending the response back to the client.
                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                    bw.write(returnMessage);
                    System.out.println("Message sent to the client is " + returnMessage);
                    bw.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void clientsend(String message) {
        try {
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write(message);
            System.out.println("Message sent to the client is " + message);
            bw.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

class TimerExampleRepeating {

    public void heartbeat(final Server srv) throws Exception {
        // Creating timer which executes once after five seconds
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Message sent to the client is I am up1");
                    srv.clientsend("I am Up");
                    System.out.println("Message sent to the client is I am up3");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                // System.out.println("Message sent to the client is I am up");
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at [Servlet 3.0 Server Push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788371/java-servlet-3-0-server-push-sending-data-multiple-times-using-same-asynccontex)

Comment: "*Sample code will be beneficial*" > Right back at you! Please post your current implementation so we can try and see what is wrong.

Comment: @duncan I have made the update

Comment: You haven't shared the client side code. Please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution for your implementation is to have a static List of Socket (instead of a single static socket). This way you would know everybody that connected there. Then you have to change the rest of the code to deal with the list, instead of a single instance.

Comment: but my above code is not working for single Socket connection also. Client is not able to receive messages when "2" is sent but if any other number is sent client gets multiplication of 2 as an answer.

Comment: In timer you have mentioned a delay of 5 seconds. Can you try in this way `timer.schedule(task,0,5000)`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework and [thread pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html). Inside a thread you can just `Thread.sleep(5000)`. It should work for small amount of clients (<50).